# Swift 4 - set up a condition for each day of the week

Tags: swift, date

Ok, let's say I want an app to randomly pick 3 days of the week that I'm supposed to do something. I have the randomly picking part worked out - I can end up with an array that is like:

```
thisWeeksPicks = [false, true, false, false, true, true, false]
```

or I could even make a dictionary that has `Monday = true, Tuesday = false, etc.`

I just have no idea where to even start to have something where if I check this on Wednesday (any time on Wednesday) the app will say "Not Today" while if I check it any time Friday (or whatever) it will say "Yes, today you must!"

I'm looking at `EventKit` but this seems like a lot more than I need - I don't need to add this to people's calendars. Thanks for any help - just getting me started would be awesome.

Comment: Why are you limiting yourself to Swift 4? Most likely any version of Swift would work.

Comment: Are you saving the data somehow? Cuz it's as simple as, user starts the app, you check if you have generated the random days for that week, if you haven't generate and store them, then check if it matches one of the days.

Comment: dfd - I don't know, wasn't sure if it would matter.

Comment: Pochi - I'll work on that, not sure how to check if the data is a week old or not to regenerate for a new week after the first...but I'd imagine I can have one of the pieces I save is a time stamp for now and check if that's older than a week..? but hmm, that would get messed up depending on when they first ran the app....thank you

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be describing something like this:

```
let thisWeeksPicks = [false, true, false, false, true, true, false]
let d = Date()
let greg = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let day = greg.component(.weekday, from: d)
let ok = thisWeeksPicks[day] // false
```